# Model Predictive Control algorithm

Tags: algorithms, control-theory, robotics

Hi StackExchange fellows,

During my internship I have to work on a mobile robot and make it follow a path. As I was doing some researches, I found this article: [Path Following Mobile Robot in the Presence of Velocity
Constraints](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/189/pdf/imm189.pdf) from *Martin Bak*, *Niels K. Poulsen* and *Ole Ravn*.

Despite several close readings, I still don't understand some points:

1) In equation *26 p.7*, the controller expression use the vector $R_k$. Because it is normally dependant on the position of the robot and not directly on time, in *p.8-9* a model $n$-step predictor is used to obtain $R_k$. But this model need to know the control law previously computed, which required to have $R_k$. So I don't understand how $R_k$ can be computed this way. Apparently the controller works, simulations have been done. But I really don't get it, so I would be glad that someone helps me to do so please.

2) Why matrices $A$,$B_\phi$ and $B_r$ in equation *19 p.6* are considered constant during the paper, while the velocity $v$ seems time-dependent (cf. equation *31 p.8* for example) ?

Thank you by advance !

Comment: I would try to ask the question also in the DSP exchange group

Comment: @ To 2), because the plant model is linear time invariant. Think about what those matrices mean, they are simply the matrices of constants in front of dynamical equations. Those constants are not going for change. For example, f = ma, a is acceleration, but m is mass. Why should mass change? In real applications, those matrices rarely depend on time.

Comment: @Moti: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it. ;)

Comment: @Beached_Whale: The plant model depend on the speed, which is not time invariant, so the matrices shouldn't be time invariant. And a simple example where mass changes: a plane, which consumes fuel.

Answer (score 1):

I have not read the paper properly. But,

It seems at each sampling time they assume the velocity $v$ will remain constant during the entire prediction horizon to simplify the cost function calculation. Also angle sinuses are considered equal to their corresponding arcs.

The vector $R$ is the reference which is updated at each sample time before MPC optimization of control input. I do not see using n-step predictor to calculate $R$. Even if you use MPC to calculate $R$, it will be via a different process from the main MPC you use to calculate inputs.